# How to explain such significant variations in performance?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a table like

```
.create table iot (ts: datetime, dim1: string, dim2: string, value: real)
```

I found a query that has a dramatic difference in performance from run to run:

```
let q1 = iot
| where dim1 == 'X' and dim2 == 'Y'
| top 1 by ts
| project NameXY = 'XY', ValueXY = value, tsXY = ts, binding = 1;
let q2 = ...;
let q3 = ...;
...
q1
| join q2 on binding
| join q3 on binding
```

Essentially it collects latest data point per certain combinations of dimensions and joins them into a single row.

*Please consider my question as purely theoretical, I am aware that there are other means to calculate the result more efficiently.*

So I discovered that execution time of the query varies from a fraction of a second to as much as 1.5 minutes (number of `let` queries and the dimensions were always same during period of my observations).

I could not "catch" long execution instances in my test, so comparing some metrics available in `.show queries`:

0.07s:

```json
"CacheStatistics": {
    "Memory": {
        "Hits": 0,
        "Misses": 0
    },
    "Disk": {
        "Hits": 0,
        "Misses": 0
    },
    "Shards": {
        "Hot": {
            "HitBytes": 51980752,
            "MissBytes": 0,
            "RetrieveBytes": 0
        },
        "Cold": {
            "HitBytes": 0,
            "MissBytes": 0,
            "RetrieveBytes": 0
        },
        "BypassBytes": 0
    }
}

"ScannedExtentsStatistics": {
    "MinDataScannedTime": "2022-10-05T00:41:28.2285664Z",
    "MaxDataScannedTime": "2022-11-16T10:43:41.8025338Z",
    "TotalExtentsCount": 195,
    "ScannedExtentsCount": 168,
    "TotalRowsCount": 1037201352,
    "ScannedRowsCount": 660165419
}
```

1min 13s:

```json
"CacheStatistics": {
    "Memory": {
        "Hits": 0,
        "Misses": 0
    },
    "Disk": {
        "Hits": 0,
        "Misses": 0
    },
    "Shards": {
        "Hot": {
            "HitBytes": 106393759,
            "MissBytes": 0,
            "RetrieveBytes": 0
        },
        "Cold": {
            "HitBytes": 179996560,
            "MissBytes": 0,
            "RetrieveBytes": 0
        },
        "BypassBytes": 0
    }
}

"ScannedExtentsStatistics": {
    "MinDataScannedTime": "2022-10-05T00:41:28.2285664Z",
    "MaxDataScannedTime": "2022-11-15T20:44:31.0044810Z",
    "TotalExtentsCount": 192,
    "ScannedExtentsCount": 168,
    "TotalRowsCount": 1036292805,
    "ScannedRowsCount": 659257190
}
```

I see that the "long" query reads more data from cold shards. The amount of reported bytes however (~170 MB) seems quite small to justify >1 minute of reading.

- Our SKU is Standard_D12_v2 x 2.
- Cache period is 30 days.
- Cache utilization has been fewer than 1% recently.
- Total number of rows in the table is 345 M.
- Total number of extents is 64.
- The queried dimensions always have recent data (from minutes to few hours ago).

**Questions:**

1. Why does the number of cold shard bytes differ between runs? Data distribution between cache and disk remains stable in regard to the queried portion.
2. Is the engine not "smart" enough to query the cache first (and only if required number of `top` rows not found, query disk)?
3. What is the date *MinDataScannedTime* and where does it come from? Seems rather arbitrary to me. It is close to minimum *MinCreatedOn* time across all extents, but not exactly equal.
4. Number (total) of rows and extents from the stats matches those in the table, multiplied by 3 (because 3 queries). But I cannot figure out why *scanned* numbers are such. I tried to filter extents with *MinCreatedOn* > than the date above, but it did not give me 56 extents (=168/3).

Comment: greatvovan, this is completely out of scope for SO. Please reach for support through the proper channels.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, is the scope for SO defined somewhere (maybe informally)? Just curious for the future. I noticed that DB performance questions are usually in the interest of SO users.

Comment: Yes. One way to see it is to mark a post for close, and then go over the list of reasons. For start, your post falls under "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.". It also falls under "A community-specific reason - Needs debugging details:
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.".

Comment: In other words, your question lacks/masks a ton of important stuff and there is no way to debug your cluster/code through StackOverflow. When you write `where dim1 == 'X' and dim2 == 'Y'`. What are the actual values that *X* & *Y* stand for? Kusto engine V2 indexes every term of 4 characters and above. for V3 it's 3 characters. Are *X* & *Y* even considered as terms? When you search for something that is not indexed, you trigger a full scan of the data. When you look for a term that is indexed but expected to appear over a certain threshold, you trigger a full scan of the data.

Comment: What was the load on your cluster during the execution? What are the workload group policies defined? Did your query ran for a long time or was simply queued? etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Now I see what you mean @DavidדודוMarkovitz, the question indeed lacks some important inputs, thanks for pointing out. After rethinking, what I am really asking about is "what could potentially account for such a huge (~3 orders of magnitude) performance difference", granted that the details you mentioned *do not change*, namely, those X and Y are constant, cluster load is negligible, there is only default workload group, with default (no) policies (meaning no queuing), etc. Basically nothing in the environment changes (seemingly), just new data arrives at some constant (and quite slow) pace.

Comment: That was just a quick demonstration for a few variables that can impact the final result. It was not an attempt to paint the entire picture. Let's get back to what I stated earlier: "When you look for a term that is indexed but expected to appear over a certain threshold, you trigger a full scan of the data". Even a cardinality difference of a single row can lead to different execution plans - index seek vs. full scan. Nothing new here. You can see the same phenomena with RDBMS. This can explain the difference. Is it the actual reason? No way to know without a real investigation.

Comment: I collected some stats from that day and found that there was a period of 34 minutes, when **everything** was performing super slow. This query was the most frequent, so it came to our attention but there were many others including several executions of `print 1` that took longer than 50 s to complete. I think we can rule out poor plan based on `print 1` instance. Seem an infrastructure problem, like slow storage or network. Is it a virtualized environment by any chance?

Comment: ... and you think that a storage/network slowness could explain `print 1` completing after almost a minute?

Comment: Well, implicitly, probably. I don't assume that `print 1` performs tons on network/storage IO, but the logic could be that on the OS level the system is blocked by overflown IO requests queue (from other stuff), which blocks you even if you need to transfer one byte. That is a speculation of course. We opened a support ticked but it does not seem to bring us anywhere. Also similar performance issues happen in virtualized environments with guest memory swapping, that's why I wondered if any parts are virtualized.

Comment: There could be so many reasons for this behavior, whether it is a virtualized environment or not. I saw so many databases on their Kneeses. Because someone plugged a USB to the server. Because a query that was scheduled to run every 5 minutes using cron, got out of tune and the executions started to pile up. Because an analyst executed a query on the biggest table in the system, for one customer, for one day, but used the non-indexed/partitioned columns for filtering.

Comment: Because some developer decided to enhance his code performance by using multithreads, exploiting unlimited resources of the system, while using a method that caused endless locks and caused in practice a serialized execution. There is really no point in this guessing game.

Comment: Some of your examples eventually converge to IO bottleneck, but the point is not to guess. As we maintain our application in production, we need to answer the question "Did WE do anything wrong?" and "How to prevent it in the future?". That's the whole idea. My hope was that someone help identify the root cause and either 1) we improve our client or infrastructure, or 2) Microsoft creates a bug or policy on their end. At this point I am prone to think that not much can be done on #1 and it is really hard to make anything moving on #2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249733/discussion-between-david--markovitz-and-greatvovan).